# Java hashCode, equals error i don't understand

Tags: java, overriding, hashcode

I have to override hashCode method in my class but i have this error:

cannot find symbol:  symbol:   variable Objects

Also, how can i add string inventor comparison in equals
my code :

```
public abstract class ThingMadeByHuman {

    protected String inventor;
    protected int yearOfInvention;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o != null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        ThingMadeByHuman thingMadeByHuman = (ThingMadeByHuman) o;
        return Integer.compare(thingMadeByHuman.yearOfInvention, yearOfInvention) == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ThingMadeByHuman: inventor:" + this.inventor + " yearOfInvention:" + this.yearOfInvention;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(yearOfInvention) + super.hashCode();
    }

    public ThingMadeByHuman(String inventor, int yearOfInvention) {
        this.yearOfInvention = yearOfInvention;
        this.inventor = inventor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to import the `Objects` class. See the Java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html). See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) by Oracle.

```
import java.util.Objects ;
```